# DataBinding support

Tags: randori

Is there a way to implement databinding similar to what we have in Flex?

I've noticed that in [lesson 9](https://github.com/RandoriAS/randori-plugin-intellij/wiki/Lesson-09%3a-Dynamic-Loading-with-ViewStack)  there is support for dataBinding using a simple template engine but once I update my model, those changes don't propagate to my view.

[Update]
This is my mediator

```
package mediators
{

    import randori.behaviors.AbstractMediator;
    import randori.behaviors.SimpleList;
    import randori.jquery.Event;
    import randori.jquery.JQuery;

    /**
     * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
     * User: jfernandes
     * Date: 23-04-2013
     * Time: 14:54
     */
    public class IndexMediator extends AbstractMediator
    {
        [View]
        public var names:SimpleList;

        [View]
        public var change:JQuery;
        private var Mike : People = new People("Mike");
        private var Roland : People = new People("Roland");

        override protected function onRegister():void {

            names.data = [Mike,Roland];
            change.click(function(event:Event):void
            {
                this.Mike.name = "Mike Lambriola";
            });
        }

    }
}
```

People class

```
package
{

    /**
     * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
     * User: jfernandes
     * Date: 30-04-2013
     * Time: 12:52
     */
    public class People
    {
        public function People(name:String)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public var name:String="";
    }
}
```

Index body

```
<body class="simpleApp">
<ul id="names" class="simpleList">
    <li id="template">{name}</li>
</ul>

<input id="change" value="Change values" type="button"/>
</body>
```

By clicking on the button I don't see Mike's name being updated to Mike Lambriola.

Comment: Could you post the code for what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current release version we haven't included our observable pattern code (v.2.6). You will see this included in the coming releases and we expect full support by v.3.0. The reason for the delay is compatibility. We needed to implement something that can be wrapped to work equally well with SlickGrid's data model versus Kendo's, for example.

That said, understand that in most JavaScript components expose their own model for databinding. So, if you are working within a single set of components, for example Kendo, you can already use their observable objects and DataSources and all works.

So, the trick (and the hard part for randori)  isn't creating an implementation. Its having one that is viable to use from AS but then shareable with other component sets should you be using multiple libraries.

Once this is released, the List, template and other randori behaviors will be updated to use it.

For now, there is very little penalty in reassigning the data to a behavior once it changed.

Mike